# How to create a static variable and call it from another class?

Tags: php, wordpress, static-variables

I have a class called DB_Bookings, within that class I have a function called `updated_variables()` within this is a simple script to look at the date of a published post and change the name of a variable accordingly.

Doing this, throughout my app I intend to use the variable and it will change dynamically per post depending on the date created.

I am struggling to call the variables from within another class. Please see my working below:

```
class DB_Bookings {

...

public function updated_variables() {
    global $post;
    $compare_date = strtotime( "2018-05-22" );
    $post_date = strtotime( $post->post_date );

    if($compare_date > $post_date) {
        $weddingNameVariable = 'db-bookingsweddingname';

        ...
    } else {
        $weddingNameVariable = 'weddingName';
    }
}

} // end DB_Bookings class
```

Then in my other class (in a file called class-db-bookings-admin.php)

```
class DB_Bookings_Admin {

...

public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {

...

    update_post_meta( $post_id, DB_Bookings::updated_variables($weddingNameVariable), $db_bookingsnew_weddingname );

...

}

} // end Class DB_Bookings_Admin
```

The idea here is that I can echo out the variable set in my DB_Bookings class and it can change based on the post date (this is essentially compensating for legacy variables as I overhaul the coding of the app).

However, it doesn't appear to be saving and I'm getting the following error

```
[22-May-2018 19:29:43 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: weddingNameVariable in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/db-bookings/admin/class-db-bookings-admin.php on line 853
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach based on comments.

```
class WeddingVariables {

    //add all of the variables needed to this class
    //you could create getters/setters to manage this data

    $variableA = "data";

    //get the variable
    public function get_variable_a() {
        return $this->variableA;
    }

    //set the variable
    public function set_variable_a( $value ) {
        $this->variableA = $value;
    }
}

//a global variable
$WeddingVariables = new WeddingVariables();

//admin class
class DB_Bookings_Admin {
    public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {
        global $WeddingVariables; //now we can access this within this method

        //get the value of a variable from the class
        $someVariable = $WeddingVariables->get_some_variable();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I'm seeing that you're missing here is declaring your variable and treating it as static within the class itself.

```
public static $weddingNameVariable;
if($compare....)
 self::$weddingNameVariable;
```

That's the basic bit you'll want to change, but there's a somewhat more complicated bit that's not correct: you're treating a non-static function as if it's static. So you may need to change your updated_variables function to be static itself. I also see that you're trying to do $post->post_date immediately after declaring global $post; but without initializing it to have any value. If you are trying to access post data sent from the client, try $_POST['some-key-here'] which is defined by PHP and accessible anywhere.

Once that's all straightened out, you can either have your updated_variables function return the new value you've set, or call the function the line before and then access the variable using DB_Bookings::$weddingNameVariable.

Comment: Thanks @D. Kendall - but how can I do this, say if I have several variable (I have around 30, not just weddingNameVariable)

Comment: You can definitely declare and initialize multiple static variables. Or even a single static variable array that holds all 30 shared variables. However, if your project is small enough to be easier to do in a single file, then Chris's suggestion of using global variables would probably be easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple of things here. First, `updated_variables()` is not a static method, although you are calling it as a static method `DB_Bookings::updated_variables()`. To use that method statically, you would need to make it a static method via `public static function updated_variables()`. That is a discussion in itself however.

There are many ways to accomplish what you want, but you could do it with a global variable.

```
<?php

//this is global
$weddingNameVariable = false;

class DB_Bookings {
    public function updated_variables() {
        global $weddingNameVariable;
        //now you can read/update this variable from within this method
    }
}

class DB_Bookings_Admin {
    public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {
        global $weddingNameVariable;
        //now you can read/update this variable from within this method.
    }
}
```

This may not be the OOP approach you are looking for, as you could utilize a static variable, but if that value you needs to change often, you'd be better managing it via other options in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow you. Essentially, ditch the function and have these as global variables sitting outside my class (there are about 30 variables to define, not just $weddingNameVariable). So, could I still have my if statement outside the class?

Comment: You could, but I would advise against 30 global variables. This is going to pollute the global space. An alternative would be to create a class that manages all of these and simply make the class itself global.